# spark.sql write to csv cause shifted column data issue when comma is there

Tags: scala, csv, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I'm using scala as programming language in my azure databricks notebook, where my dataframe giving me accurate result, but when I'm trying to store the same in csv it shifting the cell where comma(,) is coming

```
spark.sql("""
  SELECT * FROM invalidData
  """).coalesce(1)
      .write
      .option("header", "true")
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(s"$dbfsMountPoint/invalid/${fileName.replace(".xlsx", ".csv")}")
```

Here one column having data like **256GB SSD, Keyb.:**, so while writing it using above function it show string after comma(,) in another cell.
Any spark inbuilt solution appriciated...

Comment: Spark should automatically quote values that contain the separator character (you can change the quote character if you like https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option). But the software you use to read this csv file should be configured to use the same quote character as you used for writing.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jasper-M pointed out you can write the output csv with a custom separator.

In this example we use `|` as the separator:

```scala
spark.sql("""
  SELECT * FROM invalidData
  """).coalesce(1)
      .write
      .option("header", "true")
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("sep", "|")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(s"$dbfsMountPoint/invalid/${fileName.replace(".xlsx", ".csv")}")
```

*It is worth noting that [the `save` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L234) takes in a *path* to save to and not the filename itself. A `.csv file (1 file since you set` .coalesce(1)`) will be saved under this path, treating this input as a directory.*

To read the `.csv` back in, using spark:

```scala
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("sep","|")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(s"$dbfsMountPoint/invalid/${path}")
```